# Modelling a refrigeration cycle in Excel

Tags: thermodynamics, modeling, refrigeration

Is it possible to model a heat pump cycle without using tools like EES, but using Excel? I am considering to use Refprop application as an add-in in Excel, and model a heat pump cycle. Another alternative would be to create a P-h database for various fluids, and go from very complicated series of equations to find pressure, temperature, and density values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this.

I set up a sheet using vlookup to interpolate through fluid characteristics and because the source data I used (from steam tables) had a 5 degree increment I had to build an interpolation function using several vlookups / I will let you do that as it is good experience.

Comment: thank you for the confirmation Solar Mike ; i wonder if there are simpler solutions out there.

Comment: I wrote a nice formula that interpolates a value based on excel's 'smoothed line'. It looks pretty complicated, but there are only three inputs, namely Known Data Range X, Known Data Range Y, and Desired Point X.

Comment: @JonathanRSwift looks like you and I did about the same thing, but I stuck with linear interpolation as that was equivalent to manually using the steam tables. Good learning experience though :)

Comment: @Solar Mike i have found out Coolprop add-in for Excel, which seems reallly promising. http://www.coolprop.org/coolprop/wrappers/Excel/index.html